# Referencing core data attribute from declared variable

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I'm following a swift development course for beginners and am trying to make a very simple app that creates new tasks with an entered text once a button is pressed, but I am encountering a few errors that I can't seem to understand.

The errors happen in my ViewController and the editor tells me my Core Data Entity does not possess an attribute named "corename" while it very well does.

Here is a screenshot of the errors : [3 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiCNX.jpg)

And here is my code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var tasks : [Taskentity] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Get the data from Core data
    getData()
    //Reload the table view
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tasks.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]

    if (task.isImportant == true){
         cell.textLabel?.text = "  \(tasks.corename!)"

    } else {
         cell.textLabel?.text = tasks.corename!
    }

    return cell
}

func getData() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
    tasks = try context.fetch(Taskentity.fetchRequest())
    } catch {
        print("Fetching Data")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please study how to save and fetch value in core data there are numbers of awesome tutorials out there.

Comment: Core data should have array of [NSManagedObjects] type.

Comment: OK I'll try to look up more information on that. I'm still pretty curious because the instructor is also using Swift 3 and XCode 9 and it works for him.

Comment: where are you saving data in core data?Where is your core data model class.

Comment: It is Ok if he has a array of Taskentity, as long as Taskentity implements NSManagedObject @TusharSharma

Answer (score 1):

Tasks is a Array of Taskentities, you probably meant to access task.corename not tasks.corename

```
 if (task.isImportant == true){
     cell.textLabel?.text = "  \(task.corename!)"

} else {
     cell.textLabel?.text = task.corename!
}
```

And for the TableViewDelegate problem, just make sure to implement all necessary funcs... You are missing 1:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: good observation but I am  still not getting it is this something new in swift 3 ?? I can't see his core data save function

Comment: He is probably saving it from a different class. But this is definitely why he is getting the compile time errors he has (screenshot) @TusharSharma

Comment: might be possible.well I guess question is done this should be marked green soon if worked.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner, I'm looking at Apple's documentation right now about core data I see what I'm missing but somehow it's "supposed" to work I guess without the array of [NSManagedObjects] etc... The code I've pasted is missing a function in which I save my core data. Thanks for everything though.